# How to communicate between applications on android

Tags: java, android, service, aidl

I am trying to have an application that runs as a service on android, other apps will be distributed that need to communicate with it.

It has been implemented as a Service and running client apps work fine when they are packaged within the same app.

However following http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html I am having problems making this work for client applications, in particular the line

"In your implementation of ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected(), you will receive an IBinder instance (called service). Call YourInterfaceName.Stub.asInterface((IBinder)service) to cast the returned parameter to YourInterface type."

Since the applications are distributed separately I dont have access to YourInterfaceName and copying it across to the client app definitely feels like "the wrong way"

If anyone could provide a pointer to documentation / a book / source code that would be very helpful, thanks

(and forgive the irony in my name, was a bit of an in joke)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book "Pro Android 2" has a decent example on AIDL...

Comment: Yeh its rather annoying that the answer is to go offline and read a book, but the example form that book was much easier to understand than any of the online documentation, all working now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do the applications need to communicate to each other?

If it is data, then you can take a look at [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

You could also share information through `Intent.putExtra`.

Comment: Its a central service and the applications need to communicate with it to decide whether the service has started or not. The actual code is up at https://github.com/daleharvey/couch-android-launcher/blob/api/src/org/couchdb/android/CouchService.java clients that use CouchDB would need to know whether or nor it has started etc

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy (or otherwise include, or rewrite with comparable functionality) the portion of the code that does the client end of the Binder IPC's into the client projects.

Comment: Could you expand on this? I have no problem getting implementing the client code inside the client, its just that every example I see http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tool or http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html assumes that the RemoteService class is available to the client, and I cant just put all that code into the client since it would use the local version instead of connecting to the remote one.

Comment: You keep the part that forms the application side of the interface and remove the part that forms the service's side (or simply remove what instantiates it)